# Appropriate Units for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a very basic question but it's confusing me.

If we have a system of ODEs, for example a predator-prey model

$$
\frac{dN}{dt} = N f(N,P)
$$
$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = P f(N,P)
$$

where the population sizes of $N$ and $P$ have units $km^-{^2}$. Do the units of each term on the RHS have to be $\frac{1}{km^2} \frac{1}{t}$ or do they have to be $\frac{N}{km^2} \frac{1}{t}$ for the first equation and $\frac{P}{km^2} \frac{1}{t}$ for the second equation?

My confusion partly arises from this previous post [Finding units for constants in ODE's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308700/finding-units-for-constants-in-odes), in which $N$ and $P$ are both given units $population/km^2$, and the two populations are not distinguished.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The units should be consistent. So, the right hand sides must have $1/(s\cdot km^2)$ as unit and since $N,P$ have $1/km^2$ as unit, then $f$ must have $1/s$ as unit.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. So the units have to be consistent throughout the entire system of equations, not just within each individual equation?

Comment: Yes, the left- and right-hand side need to have the same units. Similarly, if your right-hand side consists of a sum of terms, all those terms need to have the same units, which must also be that of the left-hand side.

Comment: Okay, and dN/dt has to have the same units as dP/dt? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All physical laws have to be consistent in units.

if $N,P$ have units of $1/km^2$.
the left hand side must have units of $1/(km^2 t)$.